# The destination could not be found when calling BAPI locally with Cloud SDK Spring archetype

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I am following the [official documentation](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/bapi-and-rfc/bapi-and-rfc-overview) to call BAPI both on SAP Cloud Platform and locally with Cloud SDK Spring archetype. The Cloud SDK version is 3.35.0.

It works fine on SAP Cloud Platform with the RFC destination provided but the destination could not be found locally. I finished all the steps in the documentation.

Below is the code snippets.

```
public List<CostCenter> getCostCenters() {
        
        System.setProperty("jco.destinations.dir", "C:\\tools\\SAP\\destinationrfc");
        log.info(System.getProperty("jco.destinations.dir"));
        
        Destination destination = null;
        BapiRequestResult resultGetCostCenters = null;
        try {
            destination = DestinationAccessor.getDestination("s4x011rfc");
            log.info("Get destination successfully.");
            resultGetCostCenters = new BapiRequest("BAPI_COSTCENTER_GETLIST1")
                                       .withExporting("CONTROLLINGAREA", "BAPI0012_GEN-CO_AREA", "0010")
                                       .withTable("COSTCENTERLIST", "BAPI0012_CCLIST").end()
                                       .withTableAsReturn("BAPIRET2")
                                       .execute(destination);
            log.info("Get costcenters successfully.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        
        log.info("Start to get results.");
        //ResultElement re = resultGetCostCenters.get(0);
    
        return resultGetCostCenters.get("COSTCENTERLIST").getAsCollection().asList(CostCenter.class);
    }
```

I created a rfc destination file in folder "C:\tools\SAP\destinationrfc" and set the system property in my code.

[image]

Then, I started up my application in Eclipse with war deployment (Tomcat was integrated). After the application was started successfully, I tested the REST API to trigger BAPI call and got the following exception.

```
com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException: Failed to get destination with name 's4x011rfc'.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationAccessor.lambda$getDestination$1(DestinationAccessor.java:121)
    at io.vavr.control.Try.getOrElseThrow(Try.java:748)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationAccessor.getDestination(DestinationAccessor.java:117)
    at com.bosch.test.service.imp.CostCenterServiceImp.getCostCenters(CostCenterServiceImp.java:29)
    at com.bosch.test.controllers.CostCenterController.getCostCenters(CostCenterController.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:807)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestAccessorFilter.lambda$doFilter$1(RequestAccessorFilter.java:75)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.AbstractThreadContextExecutor.lambda$execute$0(AbstractThreadContextExecutor.java:317)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.SecurityContextThreadContextDecorator.lambda$decorateCallable$2(SecurityContextThreadContextDecorator.java:51)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextCallable.call(ThreadContextCallable.java:225)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.AbstractThreadContextExecutor.execute(AbstractThreadContextExecutor.java:319)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestAccessorFilter.doFilter(RequestAccessorFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.cache.CacheRuntimeException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException: Failed to get destination.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.cache.CacheUtil.lambda$wrapCallableAsFunction$0(CacheUtil.java:45)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.lambda$doComputeIfAbsent$14(BoundedLocalCache.java:2343)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1853)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.doComputeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2341)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.computeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2324)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCache.computeIfAbsent(LocalCache.java:108)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalManualCache.get(LocalManualCache.java:62)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.lambda$tryGetDestination$2ec57ad6$1(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:96)
    at io.vavr.control.Try.of(Try.java:75)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.tryGetDestination(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:95)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationLoaderChain.tryGetDestination(DestinationLoaderChain.java:84)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationLoader.tryGetDestination(DestinationLoader.java:36)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationAccessor.tryGetDestination(DestinationAccessor.java:139)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException: Failed to get destination.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.getDestinationConfigurationAsJson(ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.java:202)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.getDestinationConfigurationFromDestinationService(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:214)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.getDestinationConfigurationByTenant(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:158)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.getDestinationConfigurationByRetrievalStrategy(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:131)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.loadAndParseDestination(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:108)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.lambda$null$0(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:98)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.cache.CacheUtil.lambda$wrapCallableAsFunction$0(CacheUtil.java:42)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.resilience.ResilienceRuntimeException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.exception.ThreadContextExecutionException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.exception.TokenRequestFailedException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.exception.CloudPlatformException: Environment variable 'VCAP_SERVICES' is not defined.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.resilience4j.Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.lambda$null$2(Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.java:182)
    at io.vavr.control.Try.onFailure(Try.java:659)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.resilience4j.Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.lambda$decorateCallable$3(Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.java:181)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.resilience.ResilienceDecorationStrategy.executeCallable(ResilienceDecorationStrategy.java:210)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.resilience.ResilienceDecorator.executeCallable(ResilienceDecorator.java:197)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.getDestinationConfigurationAsJson(ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.java:189)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.exception.ThreadContextExecutionException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.exception.TokenRequestFailedException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.exception.CloudPlatformException: Environment variable 'VCAP_SERVICES' is not defined.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.AbstractThreadContextExecutor.execute(AbstractThreadContextExecutor.java:299)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.resilience4j.DefaultThreadContextProvider.lambda$decorateCallable$0(DefaultThreadContextProvider.java:26)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.exception.TokenRequestFailedException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.exception.CloudPlatformException: Environment variable 'VCAP_SERVICES' is not defined.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ServiceCredentialsRetriever.getClientCredentials(ServiceCredentialsRetriever.java:35)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.getAccessTokenForDestinationService(ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.lambda$getDestinationConfigurationAsJson$0(ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.java:191)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.resilience4j.Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.lambda$decorateCallable$1(Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.java:161)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.SecurityContextThreadContextDecorator.lambda$decorateCallable$2(SecurityContextThreadContextDecorator.java:51)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextCallable.call(ThreadContextCallable.java:225)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.AbstractThreadContextExecutor.execute(AbstractThreadContextExecutor.java:293)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.exception.CloudPlatformException: Environment variable 'VCAP_SERVICES' is not defined.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.ScpCfCloudPlatform.lambda$parseVcapServices$1(ScpCfCloudPlatform.java:174)
    at io.vavr.control.Option.getOrElseThrow(Option.java:351)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.ScpCfCloudPlatform.parseVcapServices(ScpCfCloudPlatform.java:173)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.ScpCfCloudPlatform.getVcapServices(ScpCfCloudPlatform.java:210)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.ScpCfCloudPlatform.getServiceCredentials(ScpCfCloudPlatform.java:363)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.ScpCfCloudPlatform.getServiceCredentials(ScpCfCloudPlatform.java:332)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ServiceCredentialsRetriever.getClientCredentials(ServiceCredentialsRetriever.java:32)
    ... 11 more
```

## Update

I did some testing with the destination created in environment variable. It works fine. Besides the configurations in documentation, the destination should be created in environment variable as well.

The destionation definition is very simple in environment variable. Only destination name is required. Note that the destination name should be the same as what you used in code and jco destination you created in local dir.

```
[{name: "s4x011rfc"}]
```

Comment: Hi Jerry, Can you check if the destination lookup works by setting the environment variable  "destinations" with the name of the RFC destination? If that does not work then to verify that destination lookup is the problem can you please build the RFC destination programmatically by using RFC Destination builder. The code would be something like this: DefaultRfcDestination.builder("destination name").build();

Comment: The destination could be found if I set it in the environment variable. But the way provided in the documentation is to put the destination in a folder and then set the jco destination in the code. Seems it does not work.

Comment: Hi @JerryZhang can you confirm if the BAPI call is successful when you create the `destinations` environment variable as recommended? We assume this step is simply missing the documentation. If you confirm, we can be sure and extend the docu accordingly.

Comment: Hi Marco, the BAPI call is successful with destination set in environment variable. I updated detailed info above.

Comment: Thank you Jerry for your support. We will update the document soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We extended the documentation on running BAPI calls from the local machine.
We added a [section](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/bapi-and-rfc/bapi-and-rfc-overview#set-destination-as-environment-variable) on how to maintain the environment variable `destinations` which lets the SAP Cloud SDK find the destination name.